# Writing float variable to a file using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a float variable say `$var = 1.5` and I want to write it to a file and I am doing this in a shell script. The command for writing variable to file is `echo "$var" > file_name` but this is not working for float values. It works for integer variables but not for float. I have heard that `bc` command is used while working with float variables in shell but I don't know how to use it for writing such float variables to file.

How can I write this float value to a file ?

Comment: `var=1.5; echo $var > file`

Comment: "but this is not working for float values" - says who?

Comment: You can't do floating point arithmetic in bash, but a string that resembles a float should cause you no trouble. Hmm, what is your current value of $IFS ?

Comment: Please try pfnuesel's command to verify that it works, or post the entire script you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

As per [@pfnuesel comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628721/writing-float-variable-to-a-file-using-shell#comment60853580_36628721), you should try:

```
var=1.5; echo $var > file
```

Testing result:

```
$ cat file
1.5
```